# How to stop GNU make from creating "install"

Tags: makefile

I've noticed that if you have a Makefile, even an empty one, if you have a file called "install.sh" invoking "make install" will cause make  to copy "install.sh" to "install" and set its permissions.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Call `make` with option `-r`, i.e. `make -r install`. This disables the predefined rules.

**EDIT**

Of course, you can also override the shell rule only. Simply add

```
 %: %.sh
      # empty line
```

to your `Makefile`.

Comment: Is there no way I can override the predefined rule?  I want to use make install, but only have it execute the rules I've written.  Additionally, as I preparing the Makefile for an automated system, I cannot necessarily rely on on 'make -r' being used.

Comment: Note the line containing `# empty line` must _NOT_ be indented with a TAB.  A pattern rule with no command deletes the pattern.  See the GNU make manual for details.  Another option, if you're happy to get rid of most of the built-in rules, is to add the line `SUFFIXES:` which will disable this rule and almost all the other built-in rules.